# jQuery .fadeOut applied after page switch

Tags: jquery

I'm using the method of loading content as described here http://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/ however I'm running into the issue of the jQuery function .fadeOut occurring AFTER the content is changed. So when the user clicks the navigation link the content changes, then the new content fades out then fades back in. In the demo the content fades out, changes, then the new content fades in.

Here's the only part of the jQuery that I've changed to fit my site.

```
function loadContent(href){
    $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(750, function() {
                $("header nav ul li a").removeClass("current");
                console.log(href);
                $("header nav ul li a[href$='"+href+"']").addClass("current");
                $mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(750, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
}
```

Edit: I forgot to add, this script appears to be working fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Comment: What you are trying to fadeout, `$mainContent` or `"#guts"` berfore you load the new content ?

Answer (score 0):

The way we got around this was using 2 'pages', one of which is not visible.

```
<div id="page">The actual visible page</div>
<div id="holder">The 'hidden' page</div>
```

We would then load content into holder, and fade out, fade in, then switch. Here is a basic script showing what I mean

```
<script>

    // load the content into the hidden div
    function loadContent(URL) {

        // show a loading gif or something
        $('#loading').show();

        // grab new page content
        $('#holder').load('URL', function() {

            // remove loading gif
            $('#loading').hide();

            // fade divs
            replaceDivs();

        });
    }

    // fade out old div, fade in new div, replace content and switch
    function replaceDivs() {

        // fade out old div
        $('#page').fadeOut(750, function() {

            // fade in new div
            $('#holder').fadeIn(750, function() {

                // add content to old div
                $('#page').html($('#holder').html());

                // show old div
                $('#page').show();

                // hold new div until next click
                $('#holder').hide();

            });
        });
    }
</script>
```